# Database replication using wamp?

Tags: mysql, replication, wamp

I have created a POS system for our corporation, in the HQ we have a wamp server with the main database, we also have more than 25 branches across the country.

I will setup a wamp server on each branch, so I can access its database directly when putting wamp online.

I want to make MySQL replication with all branches, so every query on any branch will affect the main database on HQ.

I tried to test but found no one to explain how to do it using wamp on different PCs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like this, you may want to think about a unique architecture known as a Star Topology.

Picture the following:

- Server HQDB with 25 databases (1 for each branch)
- Server BranchDB001 with database `branch001``
- Server BranchDB002 with database `branch002`
- ...
- Server BranchDB025 with database `branch025`

## Setup Data for HQDB

- On HQDB, create the 25 databases `branch001` through `branch025`
- Load data for each branch into their respective databases

## Setup each Branch

- Load HQDB's `branch001` into `branch001` on Server `BranchDB001`

  - mysqldump branch001 database on HQDB into a script
  - Run that script in `branch001` on Server `BranchDB001`
- Repeat this for all Branch Databases

## Setup Replication

Here is the tricky part. You want to make the HQDB the Slave of Every Branch. Unfortunately, MySQL Replication is inherently designed to be a Slave reading from one Master. (NOTE: [MultiMaster (MultiSource) Replication is being implemented in the soon-to-be-released MariaDB 10.0](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/multi-source-replication/). Since I am a MySQL DBA, I leave that to more adventurous DBAs. I need to more free time to learn MariaDB.)

Getting on with MySQL Replication, the idea is

- `RESET MASTER` on `BranchDB001` (Clears Binary Logs)
- make HQDB a Slave of a Branch (say `branch01`)
- Start Replication loading changes from BranchDB001's `branch001` into HQDB's `branch001`
- `RESET MASTER` on `BranchDB002`
- make HQDB a Slave of a Branch (say `branch02`)
- Start Replication loading changes from BranchDB002's `branch002` into HQDB's `branch002`
- ...
- `RESET MASTER` on `BranchDB025`
- make HQDB a Slave of a Branch (say `branch25`)
- Start Replication loading changes from BranchDB025's `branch025` into HQDB's `branch025`

If you have common tables to ship to every branch, simply mysqldump each branch's copy of that table and load into each branch.

All these things could be done in a maintenance cycle to update HQDB's copy of every branch

I have discussed this wild idea before

- `Apr 25, 2011` : [MySQL in star topology in StackOverflow (My 1st answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5781504/491757)
- `Apr 25, 2011` : [MySQL in star topology in StackOverflow (My 2nd answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5784578/491757)
- `Apr 28, 2011` : [MySQL in star topology in ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/264444/69271)

## CAVEAT

- Make sure your firewalls allow for DB Access in both directions

  - Branch to HQ
  - HQ to Branch
- SSH Tunneling, please

Comment: @Rolando I've been on hiatus, so I just saw this question...[tungsten replicator](https://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/wiki/TRCMultiMasterInstallation#Install_a_star_topology) has a cookbook for setting up a star topology

Comment: MariaDB 10.0 is in Alpha still, but I've been using its multi-source replication since 10.0.2.  I even got the original data set in place by stopping a running MySQL 5.5.28 slave and doing a binary copy of all the files to a new machine, dropping in the MariaDB executable and support files, starting it up, and running MariaDB's mysqlupgrade... far more painless than I anticipated.  Added the 2nd data set from Master #2 with mysqldump and configured to the 2nd master.  It's been quietly humming along ever since with no issues.  I would think it would be a a strong candidate for this scenario.