# Any solution to fix circular replication fail-over?

Tags: mysql, replication, failover, wamp

I've developed a point-of-sale system for our corporation, which has 25+ branches across the country. Each branch has its own MySQL POS database on a WAMP server.

I want every event that occurs in any one branch to be reflected in the databases of all the other branches.

Some people advised me with ring topology (circular replication), but there's a big problem with that: when one server goes down, replication will stop.

I want a more reliable solution for replicating my database.

Comment: So are you asking specifically about how to replicate the MySQL database in your system?  What kind of database replication do you currently have in place?

Comment: Why are you writing a POS system yourself? Do absolutely *none* of the off-the-shelf products meet your needs? Companies in the business of writing POS systems have already solved these types of problems. In this space, particularly because it's a critical part of the infrastructure of the company, it's almost always -ROI to develop your own system.

Comment: @NickChammas: Yes I want to replicate my database, I'm using MySQL database.

Comment: @JonSeigel: We developed it ourselves, be cause current commercial systems doesn't meet our requirements.

Comment: Wait, didn't Rolando answer this in your [last question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43816/database-replication-using-wamp) (in which he suggested implementing a star topology)?

Comment: @JonSeigel: No, it was another question, with completely different situation

Comment: Ah, I see, this topology doesn't include a central/HQ database. Got it. I stand by my first comment, though. Good luck.

Comment: I would point you in the direction of [tungsten replicator](https://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/wiki/TRCMultiMasterInstallation#Install_a_four_masters_replication) but it's not officially supported on [windows](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tungsten-replicator-discuss/Tak6d_vr2Mk/BKw6vrJDd-gJ). However, since it's written in Java, you should be able to get it to work if the first link meets your needs.

Comment: @DerekDowney: I think "All Masters" are great, could you please let me know, how can I get it to work on windows?

Comment: @SPrince I wish I could, but I've never set it up even on linux. And I rarely touch Windows, so I wouldn't be much help there.